# When to use NullBooleanField in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a button that, when clicked, should save in the database that the user has drunk water. I just wanted to check whether NullBooleanField would be the correct way to define this.

A broader question that if answered would be useful to the community is a list of optimal circumstances under which to use NullBooleanField. But I'm not asking that here. Just in case you wanted a better challenge.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `BooleanField` instead of `NullBooleanField` as later has been deprecated since Django version 3.1 [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#nullbooleanfield)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The question you need to answer to find out whether you should use the `BooleanField` or the `NullBooleanField` is actually concerning the possible states of the value of the field you want to represent in your model:

2 possible states:

- user has drunk water
- user has not drunk water

→ use `BooleanField`

3 possible states:

- user has drunk water
- user has not drunk water
- it is not known whether the user has or has not drunk water

→ use `NullBooleanField`.

**UPDATE:**

`NullBooleanField` is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#nullbooleanfield) in version 3.1. Instead use `BooleanField` with `null=True`.

Comment: Would it not also be a good idea to have a NullBooleanField if the data model is already populated lots of rows and running migration would take too long? could you not also treat `null` as `False`?

Answer (score 10):

Django 2.1 introduced `null=True` for `BooleanField`. Using `NullBooleanField` is [now discouraged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield).

So use, `x = BooleanField(null=True)` instead of `x = NullBooleanField()`

Here's a simple use case: If you only need to record the "Yes" or "No" status, use Boolean without null. But if you want to have 3 conditions say, "Yes", "No", and "Don't Know", use it with `null=True`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `NullBooleanField` only when you have three possible choices: Unknown, Yes (True) and No (False).

In your case you have only two possible values - Yes (user has drunk water) and No (user has NOT drunk water) so a `BooleanField` would be better.

One more reason to use a `BooleanField` in your case is because the default form widget for this field is a `CheckboxInput` [(docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.BooleanField), while the default form widget for a `NullBooleanField` is a `NullBooleanSelect` [(docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.NullBooleanField). And since you use a checkbox, a `BooleanField` would do the job better.

Answer (score 0):

### Take advantage of the NULL properties

I use it quite often when I need to enforce some specific constrains in my data, but allow some others. Multiple `NULL` values can coexist in a column defined `UNIQUE`. Let's take an **address** model implementation as an example:

The business rules are:

- A user can have up to 1 billing address
- A user can have multiple shipping addresses

One way to implement that is by making a single `address` table with a foreign key to the `user` and an extra flag that indicates if that address is a billing address or not:

```py
class Address(models.Model):
    ...  # <- address fields

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    billing_address = models.NullBooleanField(default=None)
```

You can now simply enforce the business rules at a database level by making `user` and `billing_address` unique together.:

```py
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['user', 'billing_address'],
            name='ensure single billing address'
        )
    ]
```

The trick to make this work is that the `billing_address` must be `True` when the address is a billing address **but it should be `None` (instead of `False`) when the address is a shipping address**.

You can further enforce the validation by adding another constraint to make sure that no `False` values are added. But this is usually not necessary and could be done at the application level:

```py
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['user', 'billing_address'],
            name='ensure single billing address'
        ),
        models.CheckConstraint(
            check=~Q(billing_address=False),
            name='no False allowed'
        )
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Biggest advantage of using `NullBooleanField` for PostgreSQL database is your table won't be re-written, any new field without `null=True` will cause a table re-write, it's fine for small tables but could take a significant amount of time and resource for large tables and you won't be able to write to your table during a re-write