# Django: NullBooleanField value False not restored properly from MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I save a `False` value in a `models.NullBooleanField` in my database it is correctly stored as `0` in the DB.  When reading it Django assigns `None`.  Here is a small code snippet to reproduce:

model.py:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    foo = models.NullBooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.foo}'
```

test.py:

```
from data.models import Test
import subprocess


def run():

    print("created in Django:")
    for val in [None, True, False]:
        t = Test(foo=val)
        t.save()
        print(t)

    print("\nSQL from Database:")
    cmdResult = subprocess.getoutput("mysql -N -u user -ppass, -e 'select foo from data_test;' mydb")
    print(cmdResult)

    print("\nDjango read from Database:")
    for test in Test.objects.all():
        print(test)
```

and this is the result:

```
created in Django:
None
True
False

SQL from Database:
NULL
1
0

Django read from Database:
None
True
None
```

I would expect the last value to be False.  I have also tried with a `BooleanField` with `null=True`. Since it is stated in the docs that this may be deprecated in future.  Nevertheless the same error occurs.

I also now how to workaround this problem using another field type.  But I would like to understand where my mistake is.  As this should be running as expected, shouldn't it?  Thanks a lot for your time and hints.

Comment: `NullBooleanField` just means that it can either be True, False or NULL in the database. Try switching to just a `BooleanField` and setting a default when it's not provided.

Comment: Thanks Brandon.  But this is not what I want.  I do need those three states (yes/no/unsure) stored in the DB.  And I want to restore them at a later stage.  So I assumed a BooleanField with optional Null value would meet this requirement.  Doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, that could be a way you can do it, but it doesn't seem like the best, because Boolean is either True or False. The optimal solution would just be a CharField with some choices (Yes, No, Unsure). The Django docs have a really good example on how to implement that. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: Still I don't understand the real use case for `BooleanField(null=True)` as stated on the same page link that you provided. If you look at the answers of this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198433/when-to-use-nullbooleanfield-in-django others do have the same understanding as I do.  But for this kind of usage my example above should work.  Hmmm...

Comment: They are not going to support `NullBooleanField` in future versions of Django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#nullbooleanfield