# Django bool field explain default is False and null is True

Tags: python, django

What does the above field specify for Django .
`models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)` . Does this mean Default value is False / null.

Comment: Found this to be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198433/when-to-use-nullbooleanfield-in-django/49198682

Answer (score 0):

It means the default value for that field is False. But also it can be empty without any values